# Error with instantiation in Java

Tags: java

I'm having issues with the abstract class idea...I've attempted to use Eclipse, but this time the IDE is just messing it up.
I've got the files uploaded. 
They should be attempted to be compiled as this

1. Container
2. Base Container
3. Height, and color exception
4. Round and square containers
5. client for containers

I have the files uploaded here: http://bit.ly/nDiObk

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
ClientForContainers.java:19: SquareBaseContainer is abstract; cannot be instantiated
                BaseContainer aContainer = new SquareBaseContainer(10.0);
                                           ^
ClientForContainers.java:31: RoundBaseContainer is abstract; cannot be instantiated
                aContainer = new RoundBaseContainer(10.0);
```

Answer (score 9):

You've declared your subclasses as abstract, too -- don't do that! The base class `BaseContainer` should be abstract, but then the child classes `RoundBaseContainer` and `SquareBaseContainer`, since they provide the missing methods and are intended to be instantiated, should not be.

Comment: I get what you are saying for the most part.   My question is how can I fix this now, [code]SquareBaseContainer.java:4: SquareBaseContainer is not abstract and does not override abstract method getLength() in Container
public class SquareBaseContainer extends BaseContainer 
       ^
1 error[/code]

Comment: Your `Container` interface has a `getLength()` method; that means that any non-abstract class that implements that interface -- and `SquareBaseContainer` does because it extends `BaseContainer` -- must provide an implementation of that method, as the error message implies. Similarly, `RoundBaseContainer` needs its own version. So define that method in both classes -- or, if you're in a hurry, delete the abstract one in `Container`!

Answer (score 2):

Abstract classes cannot be instantiated.  Extend SquareBaseContainer and RoundBaseContainer  and instantiate the subclass instead.

See [the java tutorial on abstract classes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html)

Answer (score 1):

The `SquareBaseContainer` is marked as `abstract`.  Abstract classes cannot be instantiated.  They are somewhat like interfaces, except that some methods may be defined, and instance members can be defined.

However, in this case, it appears as if you have defined all methods in the class.  If you wish for this class to be instantiable, you should remove the `abstract` keyword from the class definition.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you think the IDE is "just messing it up".  Did the IDE write this code?

An abstract class cannot be instantiated.  That means you can't do "new AbstractClass()".